# How to use WC_Order class properly?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, orders

I'm writing a Woocommerce plugin and I'm trying to get order information from the class `WC_Order`, and I get two different types of error.

In the first case, I'm using the following code:

```
public function woocommerce_loaded() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
}
```

And I get this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Order' not found in C:\wamp64\www\mysite\wp-content\plugins\tutorial-plugin\tutorial-plugin.php

In the second case, I'm using this code:

```
public function woocommerce_loaded() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    $order = $woocommerce -> WC_Order($post->ID);
}
```

And I get the following error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function WC_Order() on null in C:\wamp64\www\mysite\wp-content\plugins\tutorial-plugin\tutorial-plugin.php

And for both cases, I'm hooking my function at my `__construct()` method with the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', array( $this, 'woocommerce_loaded' ) );
```

I also tried using this class with my orders id that I have access in the Woocommerce Orders page, but it didn't work either.

I'm new in this area, I don't know what I am doing wrong. I could use some help!

Here's the complete version of my plugin code:

```
<?php

//Make sure we don't expose any information if called directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

//Check if Woocommerce is active

if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

//Check if a class with the same name doesn’t already exist
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_tutorial_plugin' ) ) {

    //Provide translation files
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'tutorial-plugin', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/' );

    //Plugin code
    class WC_tutorial_plugin {

        /**
         * Constructor for the WC_tutorial_plugin class
         *
         * @access public
         * @return void
         */

        public function __construct() {

            $this->id                 = 'tutorial-plugin'; // Id of the class
            $this->method_title       = __( 'Tutorial plugin' );  // Title shown in admin

            $this->init();
            global $woocommerce;
            $this->woocommerce_loaded();

            // called just before the woocommerce template functions are included
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'include_template_functions' ), 20 );

            // called only after woocommerce has finished loading
            add_action( 'woocommerce_init', array( $this, 'woocommerce_loaded' ) );

            // called after all plugins have loaded
            add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'plugins_loaded' ) );
            add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'init' ) );

        }


        /**
         * Initialize settings
         *
         * @access public
         * @return void
         */

        public function init() {
            // Load the settings API
            $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API.
        }

        function activate(){
            //Flush rewrite rules
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        }

        function deactivate(){
            //Flush rewrite rules
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        }

        /**
         * Take care of anything that needs woocommerce to be loaded.
         * For instance, if you need access to the $woocommerce global
         */

        public function woocommerce_loaded() {
            global $woocommerce;
            $order = $woocommerce -> WC_Order(17);
        }

        /**
         * Take care of anything that needs all plugins to be loaded
         */

        public function plugins_loaded() {
            do_action('woocommerce_init', array($this, 'woocommerce_loaded'));
        }
    }

    //Finally instantiate our plugin class and add it to the set of globals

    if ( class_exists('WC_tutorial_plugin')){
        $GLOBALS['tutorial-plugin'] = new WC_tutorial_plugin();
        $plugin = new WC_tutorial_plugin(__FILE__ );
        $plugin -> woocommerce_loaded();
    }

}
}

//Activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($plugin, 'activate'));

//Deactivation
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array($plugin, 'deactivate'));
```

Comment: You can't only get post (or post Id) for products, WordPress posts or pages  this way, but you can't get orders… You can get the order id only in order received, order pay and my account view order pages.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec OK... How would be the code to get the order id from these methods?

Comment: That are no methods but front end pages or post… otherwise you can't get any order id using woocommerce_loaded() …

Comment: OK, thanks! But still, my WC_Order class doesn't work even if I try to use it with the orders id that I already know. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You provide in your question *"the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem."* actually nobody can give you a useful answer.

Comment: OK, I've just edited my question. Now there is a version of my plugin.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Were you able to see any mistakes in my code?

Comment: There is no orders within woocommerce global variable… Try to use: `public function woocommerce_loaded() { $order = wc_get_order(17); }`

Comment: When I try this, I get a error message: **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc_get_order()**

Comment: and if you use `$order = new WC_Order(17);` instead of `$order = wc_get_order(17);` where 17 is a real order ID

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I get the same error (but with WC_Order as undefined function). I am not sure if I have everything well placed (such as my hooks, my construct and init methods, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot to find the solution for this, and in the end I found two things that can be useful:

1. we can use the init hook and put the *priority* to **100**, and then use our function in it, if you can use your code this way then it is for you:

> ```
> add_action('init', 'my_init', 1);
> function my_init(){
>     $order = new WC_Order(5273);
> }
> ```

2. The 2nd way is to fetch the order details directly from the database using the $wpdb. the order is stored in the `post` table and order details like all the default order meta are stored in the `post_meta` table

> ```
> global $wpdb;
>     // Get all customer orders
>     $subscriptions = get_posts(array(
>         'numberposts' => -1,
>         'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription', // Subscription post type
>         'post_status' => 'wc-active', // Active subscription
>         'orderby' => 'post_date', // ordered by date
>         'order' => 'ASC',
>         'date_query' => array( // Start & end date
>             array(
>                 'after'     => $from_date,
>                 'before'    => $to_date,
>                 'inclusive' => true,
>             ),
>         ),
>     ));
> ```

I found this way much useful and also if you need to get the order custom meta fields then those fields are stored in the `woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table but to fetch these you need order_item_meta id which you can get from the table `woocommerce_order_items`, you can use the code below giving it the orderIds array containing the order ids:

```
foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
            "
                SELECT m.meta_value,i.order_item_name
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as m
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as i ON 
                m.order_item_id = i.order_item_id
                WHERE `order_id` = %s and i.order_item_type = 'line_item' 
                and m.meta_key = '_wapf_meta'
                
            ",
            "$orderId"
        ), object);
        $results[] = $result;
    }
```